# Selenium - dropdown choise shows new fields. how can I update driver, so it could see them?

Tags: python, selenium, dropdown

I Got this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

myurl = "https://foobar.pl"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(myurl)

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/select'))
select.select_by_visible_text('foobar') 

time.sleep(5)
```

after selecting "foobar" an input field appears.
but after I try:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/input').click()
```

I get

> ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

How can I update driver, so it would see input, without refreshing page (I would loose my selection)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the code snippet below. You might be needing to wait between clicking and getting the field that you would like to retrieve.

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/select'))
select.select_by_visible_text('foobar') 

time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/input').click()
```

You first need to click to the field, then wait, then click again.

Comment: I added time.sleeps. It is not time. Still Doesnt work. driver has earlier page version in memory

Comment: Does the input field appears after you click something like a dropdown box? If that is correct, then you might need to click the input field first, then wait, then click again. In your code, you might need to add click to this element "select.select_by_visible_text('foobar')"

Comment: "you might need to add click to this element "select.select_by_visible_text('foobar')" - I`m trying, but i don`t know how. click() method doesnt work.

Comment: ok, i did click on that. Still. Driver doesnt see new elements :/

Answer (score 0):

This commonly occurs when JavaScript modifies the page after you interact with it. The solution is to use `WebDriverWait`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ExpectedConditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
input = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/input'))
input.click()
```